# Authenticated CORS requests for various auth methods

Tags: javascript, http, cors, basic-authentication, same-origin-policy

I would like to implement a CORS API client that supports various authentication methods. The basic pattern looks like this [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/yjrz4b05/):

```
$.ajax({
  url : "http://httpbin.org/basic-auth/jerry/secret",
  headers : {"Authorization" : "Basic " + btoa("jerry:secret")},
  xhrFields : {withCredentials : true},
  crossDomain : true
})
```

However this only works for basic auth; it fails for other authentication mechanisms, e.g. digest auth: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5db8Lfe7/). Is there some way I can perform an authenticated CORS request that will work for any standard authentication method (just like when manually opening the url in the browser).

Comment: This generally depends on on what you have going on server-side.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "yes", but it depends on the particulars of each authentication strategy.  Is it a GET or POST request?  Do you have to set custom HTTP headers?  Send cookies?

This article is my de-facto guide for everything CORS related:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Overview